# Can I register a setting with a default value then use that setting in a model's field?

Tags: python-3.x, django, wagtail

Is there any way I can `@register_setting` a setting with a default value, then use that setting in the default value for a field?  I'd like my users to be able to specify a global tax rate default, but change it per location as needed.  I'm already using a setting in another function on the same model, but believe the issue might be that it's not within a function in this case.
I tried specifying `default=8.25` in the constructor for `default_sales_tax_rate`, but that doesn't seem to work.  I am getting a `NameError: name 'DefaultSalesTaxRate' is not defined error.`

```py
@register_setting
class DefaultSalesTaxRate(BaseSetting):
    default_sales_tax_rate = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=4,
        decimal_places=2,
        help_text="Default Sales Tax Rate",
        default=8.25
    )
```

*locations.models.LocationPage(Page)*

```py
location_sales_tax_rate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2, default=DefaultSalesTaxRate.objects.first().default_sales_tax_rate)
```

I've tried assigning a variable `sales_default` to 8.25 if `DefaultSalesTaxRate.objects.all().count() == 0`, but that didn't work either.

I've also tried overriding `__init__` to add the above two lines, which left me with a new error, namely: `django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: locations_defaultsalestaxrate`

I am thinking maybe a hook or a signal to instantiate the setting in the table if it's not present, but am not sure where to hook into or where to call the signal.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by overriding `__init__`

```py
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if not self.location_sales_tax_rate:
            self.location_sales_tax_rate = DefaultSalesTaxRate.objects.first().default_sales_tax_rate
```